# Determine root folder of the web server

Tags: linux, bash, apache, perl

My Linux server use Apache web server. In most cases, by default, `/var/www/html` is the root folder of the web server. However this may differ from case by case.

I need to determine root folder by running some code, either externally calling some `bash` command, or (preferably) with `Perl` code.

Comment: What webserver are you running? apache? nginx? Are you hosting using VirtuaHost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The document root will be in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` environment variable - which can be accessed as `$ENV{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` within a Perl program.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you can use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`

> **DOCUMENT_ROOT**
>
> The document root directory under which the current
>   script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

You can find more useful $_SERVER[...] constants in the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: Your answer was first and most likely indirectly helped other user to post correct answer in Perl. I appreciate that, but since Perl solution is preferable, I had accepted the other answer. Thank you for your understanding.